# How to make UILabel to fill available space with autolayout?

Tags: iphone, storyboard, autolayout

I have a text label which can contain text in length from a few words to a few paragraphs. I want it to behave something like a `<p>` does in HTML. It is set up like this:

[image: Interface designer set up]

It is attached to the left ("Equals 18 pixels"), to the top ("Equals 31 pixels") and to the right ("Greater than or Equal").

The result looks like this:

[image]

You can see, that autolayout is right, all the constraints are fulfilled, but it is not what I wanted. It somehow misses an equalation which tells the value label to fill the maximum space horizontally it can fill. How can I set this up using Storyboards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should to the trick:

1. Remove the right constraint.
2. Drag the `UILabel` to the desired width.
3. Add a new constraint by selecting the `UILabel` and use the `Editor` > `Pin` > `Trailing Space to Superview` menu option.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I came up with. Sadly this way the labels always fill up an entire line no matter they are longer than that or not. :( (This is not bad in my particular case, but for somebody it may not fit.)

Answer (score 0):

Select your UILabel and then in **`Editor`** menu select **`Size to Fit content`**
Also remove the right constraint *("Greater than or Equal")*.

Doing this, your label will stretch horizontally to fit its content. 
This will solve your problem.. :)

Comment: As mentioned above i'll suggest you to remove the right constraint ("Greater than or Equal"). Hope this will help you

Comment: Sorry, I skipped the second part :) I've tried, but sadly the label did not take the available space this way either.